# Remove all Product images on one click of button in admin

Tags: product, product-images, magento2.4, remove

I want to remove assigned images to specific product from admin on one click of button in magento2.
Please provide specific way to implement.
[image]

Comment: Develop a custom module

Comment: Any detail how to override adminhtml file and add custom button

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom Module

First of all get all images of products  then use below Dependency Injection

Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor

Here there is method RemoveImage where you need product object and file name
so in loop if you will pass u can remove all images at one click.